# Windows 7 RDP exposed to Internet

Tags: windows, rdp

We are hosting a Windows 7 desktop Pro on a KVM machine, where a legacy software which does not run on a Windows Server 2008-16 is hosted. We are exposing it to Internet as users need to login once in a while via RDP and connect to the machine.

It has a very low intermittent use, but we need to keep the machine live 24x7. Problem is there are several security issues associated and we are not aware of many.

Can someone advise what we will need to be doing?

We are running RDP on a different port. We have FailBan and Firewalling on the Main Server, DDOS is enabled by the Data Center. Windows Firewall is enabled.

But what else do we need to be doing?

Comment: Expose only the RDP ports and make sure NLA is enabled.

Comment: https://security.berkeley.edu/resources/best-practices-how-articles/securing-remote-desktop-rdp-system-administrators Here is a list of best practices. Also, you're in luck, RDP is designed to be exposed to the internet, so that in and of itself isn't a risk, provided you do it properly.

Comment: Don't expose the RDP ports on the internet - use a VPN.

Comment: "Sure, a VPN might be something that RDP could hide behind and be considerably more secure, but you could also argue that a highly secured RDP endpoint on the public internet is comparable security-wise to a VPN" from https://blog.rapid7.com/2017/08/09/remote-desktop-protocol-exposure/

Answer (score 2):

I think your safest bet is to provision a [TS Gateway server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc731264(v=ws.10).aspx) and stand it up in front of your Windows 7 box.

TS Gateway allows for the connection to remote desktop devices over a TCP 443 port connection as opposed to an RDP port directly connected to the internet. I have implemented several of these with my clients and have noticed dramatic decreases in brute force attempts (even on boxes with RDP listening on a non-standard port).

The second option I would recommend would be to put the RDP server behind a VPN connection. Get your employees to VPN into your network, then have them log in to the RDP box.